# Extending caption bar without glass

Tags: c#, user-interface, interface, dwm

I saw that Windows 7 Wizard has the title bar extended without requiring Aero Glass. Look at this:

[image: Without Aero Glass]

[image: With Aero Glass]

I made my application to work with Aero Glass, but how about withiut it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this yet, but I think it will work, mark it as answer if you agree:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme")]
static extern int DrawThemeBackground(IntPtr hTheme, IntPtr hdc, int iPartId, int iStateId, ref RECT pRect, ref RECT pClipRect);
```

This method works, loog at [this](http://ciantic.blogspot.ro/2009_10_01_archive.html)

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to do anything. The DWM is still running when using the Basic theme, it's just not doing any accelerated rendering.

Comment: no I think you didn't understand. When the Windows Basic theme is active, that region is being black... (In my application)

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that in your question.